# calling exec() on a Qdialog in a thread doesn't work well

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.7

I want to call my_dialog.exec() in a thread,but it work bad when mainwindow(mean main thread) handling a event,i want know how to deal with this problem

this is my test program:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 500, 200)

        self.dialog = QDialog(self)
        self.dialog.setGeometry(500, 500, 200, 100)

        btn = QPushButton('click', self)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.show_dialog)

        self.show()

    def show_dialog(self):
        Thread(target=self.execute).start()

    def execute(self):
        sleep(2)
        # keep moving mainwindow untill dialog have shown
        self.dialog.exec_()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
e = Main()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

when i press the button, it will sleep two seconds first.
it's normal when there's no mainwindow's event.
but when i keep moving the mainwindow(or other event,like resize) in the two sleep seconds,both of they will become nonresponsive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot modify the GUI from another thread, use the signals.

**TL;DR;**

I share a golden rule in Qt: You cannot and should not modify the GUI from another thread. For more information read: [GUI Thread and Worker Thread](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread).

Considering the above, the natural way to interact between elements that live in different threads in Qt is to use the signals since they are [thread-safe](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-reentrancy.html) as I show below:

```
class Main(QMainWindow):
    customSignal = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        # ...

        self.show()
        self.customSignal.connect(self.dialog.exec_)

    def show_dialog(self):
        Thread(target=self.execute).start()

    def execute(self):
        sleep(2)
        # keep moving mainwindow untill dialog have shown
        self.customSignal.emit()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.it can solve this question perfectly.but can't solve my question,because i have some code afert that,it need be executed after the dialog been closed.so the dialog's exec must be blocked,program have no wait when running pyqtSignal.emot()

Comment: in addition,thank you for your the golden rule,I often find some unusual act,like move a widget in a thread,sometime no problem sometime it can;t work,now I know,use pyqtSignal